# How to create Table Dynamically with existing table fields in mysql

Tags: php, mysql, sql

Currently i'm using the table sample1. how can i create table sample2 with sample1's field dynamically?

Comment: Please explain your question neatly. Read the rules of SO first.

Comment: How can we possibly give an answer with the information you've provided?

Comment: Are you sure its the right way to do, what you are trying??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this way.

```
CREATE TABLE `sample2` SELECT * FROM `sample1`;
```

Another alternative is

If table structure is the same then you can use:

```
INSERT INTO `sample2` SELECT * FROM `sample1`;
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are using `Phpmyadmin` follow these steps

- Select table
- go to (tab) Operations > Copy table to (database.table):

Comment: No don't want to do it manually. I want to do it in dynamically.. Thanks